# how to fix 404 not found when accessing URL routes while deploying an app using nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy an angular based webapp to kube, I am trying to deploy it as static content using nginx.
The problem is the URL's are not accessible; meaning if I try to access https://website.company.com/route1, I get a `404 not found` error, I can access https://website.company.com and then click on `route1` from homepage it takes me to https://website.company.com/route1

Any guidance on what am I missing here?

Following are my *Dockerfile* and *nginx.conf.erb*

*Dockerfile*:

```sh
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY www/* /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf.erb /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb
```

*nginx.conf.erb*:

```conf
worker_processes 1;
error_log stderr;
pid /app/.nginx-tmp/pid;
daemon off;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        include mime.types;
        client_body_temp_path /app/.nginx-tmp/body    1 2;
        proxy_temp_path       /app/.nginx-tmp/cache   1 2;
        fastcgi_temp_path     /app/.nginx-tmp/fastcgi 1 2;
        uwsgi_temp_path       /app/.nginx-tmp/uwsgi   1 2;
        scgi_temp_path        /app/.nginx-tmp/scgi    1 2;
        access_log off;
        server {
                listen <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
                server_name _;
                root /app/www;
                index index.html;
                location = /__health {
                        return 200 'OK';
                        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                }

                location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                }
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

*Dockerfile:*

```sh
FROM nginx
RUN mkdir -p /app/.nginx-tmp
COPY www/* /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

*nginx.conf*

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log stderr;
pid /app/.nginx-tmp/pid;
events {
        worker_connections 768;
}
http {
        include mime.types;
        client_body_temp_path /app/.nginx-tmp/body    1 2;
        proxy_temp_path       /app/.nginx-tmp/cache   1 2;
        fastcgi_temp_path     /app/.nginx-tmp/fastcgi 1 2;
        uwsgi_temp_path       /app/.nginx-tmp/uwsgi   1 2;
        scgi_temp_path        /app/.nginx-tmp/scgi    1 2;
        access_log off;
        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name _;
                root /app/www;
                index index.html;
                location = /__health {
                        return 200 'OK';
                        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                }
                location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                }
        }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> 2020/12/18 01:43:53 [error] 31#31: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
> 2020/12/18 01:43:53 [error] 31#31: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
> ```

Comment: What does `nginx -t` show?

Comment: # nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: How are you accessing the pod on k8s? is it directly through a k8s ingress? or through a nodePort? is there any proxy that the traffic goes through before entering k8s cluster?

Comment: `index index.html;` try removing the index and see if it's working

Comment: No ,that didnt help

Comment: Anyone else has any pointers?

Comment: How are you deploying the app?

Comment: @Matt - kubectl apply -f <filename>.yml  ,appreciate any inputs

Comment: Can you paste k8 manifest file here? maybe there is an issue with Service or Ingress

Comment: Added the yml file

Comment: I am wondering if `COPY nginx.conf.erb /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb` is right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, NGINX is not going to understand a `nginx.conf.erb` file.
It looks like [<kbd>Passenger</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passenger) would allow this type of file type but the "vanilla" [NGINX image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) won't.

So you will want your file to be a simple `.conf` file and to be copied over the existing */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* file.

```sh
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY www/* /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
## off course, you'll have to rename your host file to nginx.conf too.
```

Note that for this, you will also have to fix this line in the configuration file:

```
listen <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
```

Because this a ruby erb syntax and it won't be accepted nor interpreted by NGINX.

And, because your `containerPort` is explicitly specifying that it exposes the port `3000` of the container, I would expect you will be safe with:

```
listen 3000;
```

But if this is not the case, you can use the solution prompted in the docker image documentation

> Out-of-the-box, nginx doesn't support environment variables inside most configuration blocks. But this image has a function, which will extract environment variables before nginx starts.
>
> Here is an example using docker-compose.yml:
>
> ```yaml
> web:
>   image: nginx
>   volumes:
>    - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
>   ports:
>    - "8080:80"
>   environment:
>    - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
>    - NGINX_PORT=80
> ```
>
> By default, this function reads template files in `/etc/nginx/templates/*.template` and outputs the result of executing `envsubst` to `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.
>
> So if you place `templates/default.conf.template` file, which contains variable references like this:
>
> ```
> listen       ${NGINX_PORT};
> ```
>
> outputs to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` like this:
>
> ```
> listen       80;
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx*</sup>

Comment: I tried your suggestions and updated the Dockerfile and nginx.conf,things became worse,I updated the current files and the error

Comment: I explored more and was able to resolve by change root field to `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`

Comment: Oh indeed, didn't saw this one. This is because you are mounting your HTML files to this folder as per: `COPY www/* /usr/share/nginx/html`